# Исчезает окно QDialog (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qdialog, qmessagebox

Простая программа, добавляющая строку в таблицу нажатием кнопки. Проблема заключается в том, что диалоговое окно `QDialog` показывается всего на долю секунды.

Мне нужно, чтобы оно отображалось до закрытия (мной). Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
import sys
from random import random

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTableView, QMessageBox


def show_changes(num):
    msb = QMessageBox(0, 'value', 'new value - ' + str(num) + ' added.')
    msb.show()
    sml.appendRow([QStandardItem('value'), QStandardItem(str(num))])


def randomiz():
    rand_num = round(random()*10)
    show_changes(rand_num)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
button = QPushButton('Add')
button.clicked.connect(randomiz)
tabl = QTableView()
sml = QStandardItemModel()
sml.appendRow([QStandardItem('value'), QStandardItem('0')])
tabl.setModel(sml)
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(tabl)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.resize(400,300)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`QWidget::show()`**

Показывает виджет и его дочерние виджеты,
но так как `msb` является локальной переменной, то удаляется сборщиком мусора.

**`int QMessageBox::exec()`**

Реализации: `QDialog::exec()`.
Показывает окно сообщения как модальное диалоговое окно, блокирующее, пока пользователь не закроет его.

При использовании `QMessageBox` со стандартными кнопками эта функция возвращает значение *StandardButton*, указывающее на нажатую стандартную кнопку.

При использовании `QMessageBox` с настраиваемыми кнопками эта функция возвращает
an opaque значение; используйте *clickedButton()*, чтобы определить, какая кнопка была нажата.

Пользователи не могут взаимодействовать с любым другим окном в том же приложении,
пока они не закроют диалоговое окно, щелкнув кнопку или используя механизм,
предоставляемый оконной системой.

Замените `msb.show()` на `msb.exec_()`

```
import sys
from random import random

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTableView, QMessageBox


def show_changes(num):
    msb = QMessageBox(0, 'value', 'new value - ' + str(num) + ' added.')
#    msb.show()
    msb.exec_()                                                              # <---
    sml.appendRow([QStandardItem('value'), QStandardItem(str(num))])


def randomiz():
    rand_num = round(random()*10)
    show_changes(rand_num)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
button = QPushButton('Add')
button.clicked.connect(randomiz)
tabl = QTableView()
sml = QStandardItemModel()
sml.appendRow([QStandardItem('value'), QStandardItem('0')])
tabl.setModel(sml)
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(tabl)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.resize(400,300)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]